# Android : Command line APK Generation - Size Bigger Than Eclipse Export

Tags: android, apk, release

I have two ways of generating a signed APK file for and android project.

1. Through Eclipse UI.
2. Through android command line utility.(**android update project --target 1 --path .; ant release**)

With the first approach I get an apk file with size of around 60K and with the second approach it's around 200K. Also, in the first approach I don't have to specify a target.

So, is there a way to generate the apk with the **smaller size**  and also without specifying the target.

Comment: The dex file generated with ant contains android.support.v4 package classes as well - which is the primary reason for the size increase. Although I could reduce the size significantly by using proguard - it's still much higher than eclipse export.